# How do I favorite a question in Android app

Tags: support, android-app, bookmarks

I have not found a way to tag a question as a favourite one. It could be very useful to have this feature. How can I do so?

Comment: You're totally right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you view a question, there is a time stamp when the question was posted or edited last under the question body. Tap on the time stamp and it will bring a menu up with Favorite, Share, Flag, Edit, Close (if you have enough rep) and Open in Browser.